# Chat app not scrolling when new messages added

Tags: html, angular, typescript, firebase, ionic4

[image]I've created a chat app using Ionic 4, and Firebase.  However, it's not scrolling and as a result, I can't add any more messages.

here is the html:

```html
<ion-content>
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row *ngFor="let message of messages.message">
      <ion-col size="9" *ngIf="myItinerary.userId !== message.userId" class="message other-user">
        <span>{{message.content}}</span>
        <div class="time" text-right><br>
        {{message.createdAt | date: 'short'}}</div>
      </ion-col>

      <ion-col offset="3" size="9" *ngIf="myItinerary.userId === message.userId" class="message me">
        <span>{{message.content}}</span>
        <div class="time" text-right><br>
        {{message.createdAt | date: 'short'}}</div>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>

<ion-footer>
  <ion-toolbar light="light">
    <ion-row align-items-center no-padding>
      <ion-col size="10">
        <textarea autosize maxRows="3" [(ngModel)]="newMsg" class="message-input"></textarea>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col size="2">
        <ion-button expand="block" fill="clear" color="primary" [disabled]="newMsg === ''" class="msg-btn"
        (click)="sendMessage()">
        <ion-icon name="ios-send" slot="icon-only"></ion-icon>
      </ion-button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

This is the example I found and it works...I can add messages but it just won't scroll.  I'm not getting an error

I'm adding the .css per the posters suggestion...it's not working either but I'm probably not doing it correctly.

```css
.message{
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    white-space: pre-wrap
}

.other-user{
    background: var(--ion-color-tertiary);
    color: #fff;
}

.me{
    background: var(--ion-color-secondary);
    color: #fff;
}

.time{
    color: #dfdfdf;
    float: right;
    font-size: small;
}

.message-input {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid var(--ion-color-medium);
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    resize: none;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.msg-btn {
    --padding-start: 0.5em;
    --padding-end: 0.5em;
}

.style{
    display: "flex";
    flex-wrap: "wrap";
    overflow: "auto";
}
```

Added css per

Comment: I replicated your code and it works fine. It is scrolling. If you want to scroll after sending a message, you can use scrollToBottom() on ion-content reference

Answer (score 0):

you can add overflow or wrap the div, additionally you can add one stylesheet is implemented by overflow:auto and width:100% or height:; if is horizontal or vertical;

- https://angular.io/api/animations/style

  ```
    style({ display: "flex", flex-wrap: "wrap", overflow: "auto" })
  ```

Comment: I added the .css per your suggestions but I'm not sure if I'm doing that correctly

Comment: Also tried this:

  <div style="display:flex; flex-wrap:wrap; overflow:auto;">
to no avail

Comment: try with overflow:scroll;

Comment: Added screen-shot.  Add overflow-scroll to <ion-grid overflow:scroll;  >?
Do you think the problem is I'm using ion-grid?

Comment: fixed with ion-list

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by replacing ion-grid with ion-list.

```html
<ion-content>
  <ion-list lines="none">
    <ion-item *ngFor="let message of messages.message">
      <div size="9" *ngIf="myItinerary.userId !== message.userId" class="message other-user">
        <span>{{message.content}}</span>
        <div class="time" text-right><br>
        {{message.createdAt | date: 'short'}}</div>
        </div>

      <div offset="3" size="9" *ngIf="myItinerary.userId === message.userId" class="message me" slot="end">
        <span>{{message.content}}</span>
        <div class="time" text-right><br>
        {{message.createdAt | date: 'short'}}</div>
        </div>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```